# Вывод большого количества блоков на страницу

Tags: javascript, css3, html

добрый день. Пишу сайт каталог.
Можно как то автоматизировать вывод продуктов на страницу?
должна быть картинка-ссылка с предпросмотром. (или как лучше сделать?) + гибкое расположение на странице.

`<div>
<img src=img.jpg>+описание
</div>`

Вручную прописывать каждый блок и располагать его на странице очень сложно, а если их штук 200?
И посоветуйте как сделать добавление новой продукции для пользователя.
Заранее благодарю!
П.С. желательно реализовать это через js и css
К примеру взять цикл ++1, который будет выводить пронумерованные фотографии-ссылки  на страницу и брать описание из тхт файла, тоже пронумерованного.

Comment: на чем вы пишите свой сайт каталог то, на чистом html что ли?

Comment: html, css, js)))

Comment: на чем посоветуете?

Comment: В очень общем виде ответ на ваш вопрос звучит так: для таких целей создаются так называемые системы управления содержимым (cms). Они могут быть созданными самостоятельно, а могут быть взяты уже в виде готовых решений (WordPress).

Comment: А можно решить этот вопрос без CMS? так сказать погимороить в научных целях))

Comment: Можно и даже полезно. Но одним вопросом общего характера вы не обойдетесь. У вас сразу несколько задач: создание данных (реализация добавления информации), сохранение, чтение из файла (или из базы данных), обновление данных и удаление. Все это требует пошаговой реализации. Это и будет своего рода cms, только уже вами написанная.

Comment: сложите все ваши сведения тогда в `json` файл. загружайте его при открытии страницы, обрабатывайте циклом и добавляйте блоки на страницу.

Comment: Почти написал без БД и ЦМС когда прочитал последнее сообщение. json скорей всего пригодился бы) но все равно почитаю для расширения кругозора, спсибо за ответ.